# Inheriting a trait twice

Tags: scala, inheritance, linearization

This doesn't work:

```
trait Trait
class Class extends Trait with Trait
```

Compiler complains:

```
<console>:8: error: trait Trait is inherited twice
       class Class extends Trait with Trait
                           ^
<console>:8: error: trait Trait is inherited twice
       class Class extends Trait with Trait
                                      ^
```

This does:

```
trait Trait
class Abstraction extends Trait
class Implementation extends Abstraction with Trait
```

Questions:

- Why does it work?
- How is the second snippet different? (concerning the double inheritance issue)
- Is the second snippet or pattern somehow useful?

Comment: Do you have a practical example where it is a real problem that the first doesn't work?

Comment: The purpose of the question is not to find out why the first one does not work, but rather why the second one does.

Comment: Useful link: [chapter from Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#i-1280910181-1) showing how linearization works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Second snippet works because of trait linearization. The compiler will organize the traits into a linear list so that `Trait` only appears once. I think the linearization is

```
Implementation, Trait, Abstraction, ScalaObject, AnyRef, Any
```

See [this chapter](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ScalaObjectSystem.html#Linearization) from Programming Scala for a great explanation.

This is primarily done to have a consistent approach to the diamond inheritance problem and is useful in that case.

Since `Trait` cannot appear twice after linearization, it does not make sense to write `Trait with Trait` and it makes sense to be disallowed.

Comment: Answer is very old so maybe scala changed this behaviour but for me right now it looks like this is wrong.
Linearization should be: Implementation, Abstraction, Trait, ...