# Why Scala's traits execute from right to left?

Tags: scala

For example, this:

```
val queue = new BasicIntQueue with Doubling with Incrementing with Filtering
queue.put(1)
println(queue.get())
```

will print:

```
Filtering
Incrementing
Doubling
put
4
```

As for me it would be more readable if it executed from left to right, in the order I wrote operations.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Scala, but I'm guessing just how that code is parsed. So it's `(((new BasicIntQueue with Doubling) with Incrementing) with Filtering)`, and expressions like that are evaluated innermost-paren-first.

Comment: Yes, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230808/inheriting-a-trait-twice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't think 'executing', because it's not... think 'layering': if you add another `with XYZ` on the right, you've added another layer on top.

Answer (score 7):

Because it follows the same pattern as inheritance. Imagine that you had something like this:

```
class BasicIntQueue 
class Doubling extends BasicIntQueue
class Incrementing extends Doubling
class Filtering extends Incrementing

val queue = new Filtering
```

You'll get the same results as you saw: `Filtering` gets executed first, then pass on to `Incrementing`, then `Doubling` and finally `BasicIntQueue`.

Answer (score 3):

The truth is more complicated, see the [Language Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) "5.1.2 Class Linearization" (page 56), or the explanation by [Jim McBeath](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.de/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the diamond problem of multiple inharitance